# How to stop BrowserWindow from breaking after a single error in executeJavaScript?

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm using the `executeJavaScript` method to control a page via Electron. However, I've noticed that the `BrowserWindow` instance essentially becomes unresponsive after one error occurs. Aside from putting every single line of code in a `try`/`catch` block, is it possible to disable this functionality?

Specifically, I'd prefer that the `BrowserWindow` continues to execute future code despite running into an error on a previous request. For example, in the code below, I want the console to successfully output `I'm not being executed`.

```
const {BrowserWindow, app} = require('electron')
async function main() {
    var win = new BrowserWindow({webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: false} });
    win.openDevTools();
    win.loadURL('https://www.homedepot.com');
    await sleep(10000); //letting page load
    await win.webContents.executeJavaScript('console.log("Im being executed")')
    await sleep(2000);//break
    await win.webContents.executeJavaScript('undefinedVar.causeError()')
    await sleep(2000);//break
    await win.webContents.executeJavaScript('console.log("Im not being executed")')
}
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
app.on('ready', main)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't believe the `BrowserWindow` is unresponsive after executing the broken code. You can still move it around and maximize it, etc. It's just that the `Promise` returned by `executeJavaScript` is stuck in a pending state, and so you never finish `await`ing it.

This is actually fixed in Electron 6 by [this pull request](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/18635). In Electron 6, you can do this:

```
var win;
async function createWindow2() {
  win = new BrowserWindow();
  win.openDevTools();
  await win.loadURL('https://www.google.com');
  await executeSafely('console.log("Im being executed")');
  await executeSafely('undefinedVar.causeError()');
  await executeSafely('console.log("Im not being executed")');
}

async function executeSafely(code) {
  try {
    await win.webContents.executeJavaScript(code);
  }
  catch (e) { } // assuming you want to ignore errors
}
```

If upgrading Electron isn't an option for you, then you can create a function that wraps your code in a `Promise`, or a `try/catch` depending on what you need.

If you just want to ignore all errors, then wrapping your executed-code in a `try`/`catch` is sufficient. Otherwise, you can wrap in a `Promise`, which should result in the `Promise` returned by `executeJavaScript` being rejected. Example:

```
async function main() {
  var win = new BrowserWindow();
  win.openDevTools();
  win.loadURL('https://www.google.com');
  await sleep(5000);
  await win.webContents.executeJavaScript(makeSafe('console.log("Im being executed")'));
  await win.webContents.executeJavaScript(makeSafe('undefinedVar.causeError()'));
  await win.webContents.executeJavaScript(makeSafe('console.log("Im not being executed")'));
}

function makeSafe(code) {
  return "try{" + code + "}catch{}";
}
```